# Alternative to PNUnit for parallel Unit Testing

Tags: .net, testing, nunit, pnunit

I have been working on Parallel Unit Testing with the help of PnUnit (Parallel NUnit) in one of my project.

Now I want to replace this which is equivalent to  PNunit for parallel testing which can run with NUnit or XUnit in dotNet.

Can anyone suggest me the alternative for this.

Comment: Any specific reason that PNUnit doesnt work for you? As long as they are pure micro/unit tests, you can use a shell/c# script to fork multiple NUnit processes and then collate the results at the end. If the tests need to be parallelized across machines, you'd need a more beefy tool/script

Comment: It works completely fine, The reason is it just run around 5-10 users on one machine. I want around 30-50 users on one machine.

Comment: Are these unit tests or load tests ? Because Microsoft has a load test tool that simulates simultaneous users with arbitrary values..

Comment: These are load tests.where we give the load to system by logging multiple users at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

PNUnit seemed to be the best option available. Other Parallel unit testing tools available but they are not free.